# Disable or adjust threshold using sonar-project.properties file

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to set threshold for test parameters using the sonar-project.properties file?

I know this does not work but I'm looking for something like this

```
sonar.javascript.test.cognitivethreshold.value = 16
sonar.javascript.test.cognitivethreshold=off
```

Also is there a good source for documentation on how to configure these?